# Request data from a MySQL Table and show on an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, node.js

Title,

I've tried Node.JS but to no avail since it doesn't work for webpages, and looking into it online it always suggests on how to show HTML through Node.JS, not mentioning SQL in the slightest.

I've got little to no experience with PHP, but for my general understanding, I'd have to turn my index.html into an index.php file, and for some reason if I do that, AWS Amplify (the service I use to deploy my website) simply ignores the PHP file and displays a blank page.

I need to fetch one specific piece of data (an integer) through an SQL query and keep the number updated on my webpage (similarly to how a setInterval would work in JS)

How would I do that?

Comment: _NodeJs doesn't work for webpages_ Well thats wrong, so obviously you have not done sufficient reseach. [Connecting to the MySQL Database Server from Node.js](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/connect/) and [https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch002070.htm](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch002070.htm)

Comment: @RiggsFolly what I meant was, you can't use Node.js inside a JS file for a website, once again, I have little to no experience with this sort of thing and I apologize if my question was vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server side language and needs a service to process the code inside .php files.

AWS Amplify is used for front end technologies, this would refer to JS and html, JS and HTML can be parsed by your web browser, when the browser requests the file. Because the Web browser can interpret and execute the JS you do not need a specific service to run this.

If you need to load dynamic data I would look into using firebase

However if you still want to use a backend stack such as PHP + MySQL you will need to host the php files on a web server such as nginx/apache and set it up to parse PHP files.